# How to increase Application cache (appcache) size limit in IE11 and Microsoft Edge on Windows 10?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, html5-appcache

We ran into a unique sequence of unfortunate events with out web application's offline functionality. It needs about 85MB of content to be stored in browser application cache (HTML5). Before Windows 10 for IE11 it could be set using GPO "Set application cache storage limits for individual domains". But on Windows 10 tablets with 128GB SSD drives having only IE11 and Edge this doesn't work anymore.
It runs into 50 MB limit on the following configuration:

- **OS**: Windows 10 Enterprise - (no problem on win8 and win7)
- **Browsers**: IE11, Edge - (Chrome and Firefox do not have any problems)
- **Volume size**: 128GB or less (with 256GB appCache can go up to 100MB but no further) on C drive, more than half of it is free.

The site (and the domain is included in IE list of trusted sites of course) and uses HTTPS

References:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt732551(v=vs.85).aspx
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/networking-and-connectivity/application-cache
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj891001.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just got a call from the Microsoft IE developer support team. Turns out Windows 10 is missing some registry settings that are present in prior versions. So to increase app cache limit you have to set following:

- For **IE**:

  ```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserStorage\AppCache
  ```

  Key "MaxTrustedDomainLimitInMB" value is size in MD and also may help to set value for the key "TotalLimitInMB"
- For **Edge**:

  ```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\BrowserStorage\Appcache
  ```

  Same keys and values as for IE above

Comment: BrowserStorage is missing in Windows 10 in the registry for both of the keys above.